# Chromium Browsers replaces https instead of http for loading images in .NET Core

Tags: c#, google-chrome, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have recently published my [website](https://heilton.com) and I load my images from a download host like this

```
<img src="@Model.ImageLink" />
```

The problem is that my website has SSL but my download host doesn't. In Chromium browsers (ig Edge & Chrome), it replaces https instead of http for loading images and because my download host doesn't support SSL, it returns a 404.

I use ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. I want to do something so Chromium browsers doesn't change this automatically

Comment: Try to get your download host to support SSL. It's state of the art today, and any service not supporting it should be avoided IMHO.

Comment: Click the lock icon in left in the url bar of the browser when you are on that page go to settings in the menu and in the shown list of permissions find "insecure content" and set it to allow. And yes that must be done on the client. Its a client security thing and beeing able to disable that from the server would be BS.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to clarify what part of it relates to programming?